# Weird spacing with tcolorbox and altered display skip

Tags: math-mode, spacing, tcolorbox, vertical-spacing

As per the title, I'm utilizing tcolorbox and messing with quite a few things, such as the box layout and display skips. I've reduced this down to as minimal as i can get it before it stops happening. It seems that:

- Every length that is altered must be altered
- Every option that is set for tcolorbox must be set, except for `beforeafter skip` which is there to highlight the effect.
- The box must be broken over two pages.
- The lengths of the text used are important.
- The array must be there?

In any case, here's the most minimal example I could get:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbsetforeverylayer{
    % following line makes overlap more noticeable but is not necessary
    beforeafter skip=0pt,
    frame hidden,
    boxrule=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    breakable,
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \addtolength\belowdisplayshortskip{-5pt}%
    \addtolength\abovedisplayshortskip{-5pt}%
    \addtolength\abovedisplayskip{-5pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
\lipsum[5][1-2]
\\

\section{}

short phrase
\[ U, W \in \Sigma_V \implies U \cup W \in \Sigma_V \]
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[6][2]
    \[ \begin{array}{ll} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{array} \]

    \lipsum[6][3]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

And here's a screenshot of what's happening:
[image: The weird spacing I do not want to see.]
As you can see, the top of the box "eats" the subscripts and the bottom of the comma.

Thank you all in advance and I'm sorry if this question is too specific.

Comment: Clearly, the decrementing by 5pt of the various display skips seems to be at the root of the issue.  Reducing those decrements to 2pt or even 3pt helps to eliminate the issue.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I agree that that seems to be the root cause, but shouldn't the correct skip be applied such that there's no overlap?

Comment: In general, I don't think those skip values were intended to go negative.

Comment: They're not negative though, that's addtolength not setlength.

Comment: I see your point, however, `\abovedisplayshortskip` is actually negative in absolute terms.  Also, `\belowdisplayshortskip` has enough glue to make it go negative, as well.